# DisplayAttribute and DisplayNameAttribute combined into one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my POCO declaration, System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute is used in MVC applications, while System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute is used in other applications.

```
[Display(Name="Trade name")]
[DisplayName("Trade Name")]
public string TradeName { get; set; }
```

duplicate declaration of the same text for various look redundant to me. I just wonder if there exist a way to force MVC to use DisplayAttribute?

Comment: you can use one in all applications. can't you?

Comment: `[Display(Name="Trade name")]` is used by MVC and has the advantage of setting other properties such as `Order` There is no need to use `[DisplayName("Trade Name")]` in MVC